# Jquery long press, stop short press action not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to implement one event for a short press and a different for a long press. The short press is just doing the default action. The long press works, but also does the default action still. What am I missing?

```
  HTML
   <a href="http://myLocation" class="recordlongpress"><"Label for my Link"</a>

  Javascript
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.recordlongpress').each(function() {

        var timeout, longtouch;

        $(this).mousedown(function() {
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                longtouch = true;
            }, 1000);
        }).mouseup(function(e) {
            if (longtouch) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#popupPanel').popup("open");
                return false;
            } else {
                return;      
            }
            longtouch = false;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        });

    });
});
```

I followed the jQuery documentation and was under the impress "preventDefault" should stop the short press default action. Any examples I have found online do not seem to be exactly my situation. I appreciate you taking the time to read this. Thank you for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Pointy lead me towards a working solution for clicking events.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.recordlongpress').bind('tap', function(event) {
        return;
    });
    $('.recordlongpress').bind('taphold', function(event) {
        $('#popupPanel').popup("open");
    });
});
```

Something still needs to be added because upon a long press on my mobile device, the default options screen with the four options; open, save link, copy link URL and select text still pops up as well. I will add on the fix for that once I find it.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning from your "mouseup" handler before clearing the timeout and setting "longtouch" to false.

Try:

```
    }).mouseup(function(e) {
        var returnval;

        if (longtouch) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#popupPanel').popup("open");
            returnval = false;
        } 

        longtouch = false;
        clearTimeout(timeout);

        return returnVal;
    });
```

I'd also clear "longtouch" in the "mousedown" handler. That said, I wouldn't do this with mouse events. I'd use "touchstart" and "touchend".  On touch screen devices, "mouse" events are simulated from touch events, and there's a distinct delay involved.  (You may also want to detect whether the finger moved during the touch period.)

Comment: I have tried your code it seems to generate the same problem. I am going to put it into a jfiddle to show

Comment: Well I really think that the basic problem is that you're trying to use "mouse" events, which don't really exist on a touch screen.

Comment: yes I am new. Was not aware of those, but I am testing this on my PC. Would the logic be the same for mouse and touch events or would solving this problem not apply to using the touchevent functions?

Comment: Touchscreen devices simulate "click" from "touch" events. It's a fairly clunky process, which is why some libraries exist to do a better job.  In your case, if you were to handle touch events directly, you could just avoid handling "click" on touch-capable devices and do everything via the "touch" event. In the "touchend" handler, you'd either take the long action or the short one, in other words. (You could still deal with "click" events on a mouse-oriented client.)

Comment: sounds like I should drop this problem and read about touch events, although I wish I understood why my code did not work. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

## [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ABc56/5/)

In your code  these lines are unreachable

```
     longtouch = false;
     clearTimeout(timeout);
```

**JS:**

```
 $('.recordlongpress').each(function () {

    var timeout, longtouch = false;

    $(this).mousedown(function () {

        timeout = setTimeout(function () {
            longtouch = true;
        }, 1000);
        e.preventDefault();
    }).mouseup(function (e) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        if (longtouch == true) {
            longtouch = false;
            $('body').append("long press" + longtouch);

            return false;
        } else {
            return;
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: I tried your demo and it seems as though it still tries to attempt the click event on a long press and it also will execute the long press event if you click it more than once. thanks though

Comment: @Four_lo I have updated the fiddle.. check if that is what you want

Comment: @Pointy .. Really ?? Can you please check that again.

Comment: @MohammadAdil well it's been edited since I added that comment, so now it's different.

Comment: @MohammadAdil if you give the href an action besides # it tries to execute that action on a long click still

Comment: @MohammadAdil jfiddle prevents browser from being rerouted to google, but if you hold down ctrl key so that it will open in another browser it appears that it still open on a long click. unless I am wrong and holding the ctrl key is overriding something?